# Installing Third Party Modules - Automate the Boring Stuff Chapter 6 - Appendix A

Tags: python, importerror

[Automate the Boring Stuff (ATBS) - Chapter 6](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter6/)

[ATBS Appendix A](http://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/appendixa/#Installing%20Third-Party%20Modules#Installing%20Third-Party%20Modules)

MacOS, working through ATBS Ch 6, and I've been asked to read Appendix A and download and install requisite 3P modules for python. To do so I was asked to download the [requirements files](https://nostarch.com/automatestuff2/) locally, and then run the following command in a terminal:

```
$ pip3 install --user –r automate-mac-requirements.txt --user
```

Doing so results in the following error:

```
ERROR: Invalid requirement: '–r'
```

I've read `pip install -h` but can't understand what to do to fix the problem.

I've tried removing -r flag which results in:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement automate-mac-requirements.txt (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for automate-mac-requirements.txt
```

I've tried replacing the .txt filename in the command with the full path, but the error is the same.

I've tried replacing the file in the command with the full path, as well as removing the -r flag, which results in:

```
ERROR: Invalid requirement: '/Users/{user}/Downloads/automate_online-materials/automate-mac-requirements.txt'
Hint: It looks like a path. It does exist. The argument you provided (/Users/{user}/Downloads/automate_online-materials/automate-mac-requirements.txt) appears to be a
 requirements file. If that is the case, use the '-r' flag to install the packages specified within it.
```

If I add the flag -r, I'm back where I started.

To move forward I will try manually installing the modules from Appendix A (eg `pip install --user send2trash==1.5.0, ...`). Doing so seems to work for some modules but throws other errors in various cases.

Appreciate help in understanding what is going wrong in attempting to install all 3P modules from the file per the seemingly basic instructions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo in the book. He uses `–r` instead of `-r`

Try using `pip3 install --user -r automate-mac-requirements.txt --user`

Comment: those are the same -r flags... no?
your pip3 command is the exact same as mine.

Comment: There is a subtle difference between the characters there that the answer could have elaborated explicitly on. One is a typeset en dash (U+2013), the other one is the intended minus sign (U+002D).

Comment: Old post, but this really helped me. I never would have noticed such a small difference. Thanks so much.